# How to change "Your Order" title in woocommerce checkout (Customify theme) - translate to german

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I am a complete novice and need to change the "Your Order" title to "Deine Bestellung" on the checkout page of my WordPress (WooCommerce) page, built with the Customify theme.

http://nachhaltige-bildung-afrika.de/checkout/

I tried various "translate" code snippets, but they didn't work. I cannot find the checkout.php fine in my theme folder. I have a child theme, but it isn't there either and adding code to the child functions.php also did not work. Anyone know how to change this? I would much appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In most cases the used WordPress theme has a translation file in .po file format. The location of these files is in the directory of the theme itself (mostly in a language folder) or at `wp-content/languages/themes` or in a subfolder of a installed WordPress plugin.

You can edit these .po files with a tool called [PoEdit](https://poedit.net/). It 's freeware and ready to use after you 've downloaded it. Just open the .po file of your active theme and search for the phrase you want to translate. Keep in mind, that you have to create a new .po file in german format `de_DE`. In PoEdit you can chose at the beginning what you want to do. Just chose `create translation from existing file`. Then you have to chose the language you want to translate to and then just save this file.

Beware. Badly coded WordPress themes are not using the translation support of WordPress. To prove that, just have a look in the templates of your used theme and check, if the used phases are outputted with one of WordPress' [l18n](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers) functions.

Answer (score -1):

You can edit the .POT file of your main WordPress Theme adding the required string (in this case "Your Order") using a plain text editor, like Notepad++, Sublime or similar.

Just take the same format used on all the another rows presents in that file.

After that, the string appears readable and editable into the Poedit program.

Comment: The solution is for a website for German speakers only.